# I'm Installing Docker but i'm confused about container, did i install or not, how may i confirm container is installed or not?

Tags: docker, containers

I'm new in docker, i have enabled Hyper-V and Container from Apps And Features but now i'm confused about container, should i externally install or is it built-in in windowS?

Comment: container is an instance of an images. docker ps shows running container, docker images shows your images and so on

Answer (score 0):

On either Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 you'll need to setup the Docker engine.  Using PowerShell:

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider

See Microsoft's instructions here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Install process outlined above, you'll want to consider the following, using PowerShell:

1)   New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Docker Inbound' -Profile @('Domain', 
    'Public', 'Private') -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -
    LocalPort 2375
2) Setup the daemon.json file:
    cd c:\programdata\docker\config\
    new-item daemon.json -type file
    set-content daemon.json
    { "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "npipe://"] }
3)  Start the daemon at command prompt >dockerd
4)  confirm dockerd process is running, and then proceed to have fun with Docker!